# Constructor gets ignored

Tags: c++, constructor

my constructor gets ignored somehow. Here is my code:

My class:

```
class field
{
private:
    char PlayField[5][5];

public:
    char o = 'o';
    field()
    {
        char PlayField[5][5] = { { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o } };
    }


    void setTile(int x_val, int y_val)
    {
        PlayField[x_val][y_val] = 'x';
    }
    char getTile(int x_val, int y_val)
    {
        return PlayField[x_val][y_val]; 
    }



    /*field::~field();*/
};
```

The constructor field() should initalize my 4 wins field with 'o's and if I want to add a Tile it will x mark where the tile is. 
But if I do

```
int main()
{
    char x;

    field FourWins;
    //FourWins.setTile(3, 2);
    x = FourWins.getTile(3, 2);
    std::cout <<  x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The constructor will get ignored and I get a weired sign which is most likely just currently at where I'm looking. 
The position finding works, becouse if I first set and x to (3,2) it will print me the x.

Any ideas?

Comment: [*warning: unused variable 'PlayField'*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8f91ad81e315d48)

Comment: `char PlayField[5][5]` in your constructor makes a _new_ variable `PlayField` that shadows the class member.

Comment: Oh I see.. any hints on how to do it properly?

Comment: @Yíu Use a `std::vector` to do it properly.

Comment: The answers below show you the problem, but I would also point out that if you added a `cout` statement into your constructor you would see that it is definitely not getting ignored - just not doing what you thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ideone example here](http://ideone.com/NrZnxu)

The initialization syntax for `char[][]` you used is allowed, but only at construction - not assignment (and your example *constructed* a new variable rather that *assigned* to the member variable). At least with C++14 you can do it like this:

```
class field
{
private:
    char o = 'o';
    char PlayField[5][5];
public:
    field() : PlayField{{ o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, 
                        { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, 
                        { o, o, o, o, o }}
    {}
};
```

Consider using `std::vector` of `std::vector`, or `std::array` of `std::array` instead. The only down side of using `std::array` compared to `char[5][5]` is that the sizes (5x5 in your case) must be known at compile time (just as in your example)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char o='A';

    // C++11 or later:
    std::array<std::array<char,5>, 5> PlayField2{{{o,o,o,o,o},{o,o,o,o,o},
                                  {o,o,o,o,o},{o,o,o,o,o},{o,o,o,o,o}}};

    // or: (C++11 or later)
    std::array<std::array<char,5>, 5> PlayField;
    for(auto& row : PlayField){
        for(auto& place : row){
            place=o;
        }
    }
    cout << PlayField[2][3] << std::endl;

    // or: (C++98 or later)

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> PlayFieldVec(5,std::vector<char>(5,o));
    cout << PlayFieldVec[2][3] << std::endl;

}
```

The syntax you used for array initialization is fine, just make sure you don't assign to a *new* variable if you mean to initiate an existing one.

Comment: Your first example: Not all compiler support that (yet). VS2013 has not the needed C++14 compatibly. LLVM outputs a warning that o is used before initializing as o defined after PlayField (that should not be as it is a attribute, maybe a bug?)

Comment: @MartinSchlott, Thanks. I added comments about what version support what solution. As far as I know, also in C++14, members are always initialized in declaration order, so I moved o to before PlayField.

Answer (score 1):

The error you made is, that you define PlayField twice:

```
class field
{
private:
    char PlayField[5][5];
         ^^^^^^^^  class attribute

public:
    char o = 'o';
    field()
    {
        char PlayField[5][5] = { { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o } };
        ^^^^ this 'char' made a second PlayField local! a common mistake
    }
```

so, it initialize only the local array, not the class attribute one.

Unfortunately -as far as I know- there is no way to explicit init an array beside using two for loops:

```
for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
  for(int y=0;y<5;y++)
   PlayField[x][y]=o;
```

At the end, your constructor wasn't ignored, it has not the effect you wanted :-)

Comment: this was already said in the first answer: "You are defining a local variable in your constructor."

Comment: @JohanLundberg not in the answers I saw so far as I started. During writing I cross checked it with VS2013 if there is a C++11 way wich work with the current Compiler. That takes time.

Comment: Thank you for taking that time, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value to an array like this. You are defining a local variable in your constructor. You can do like this in your constructor.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        PlayField[i][j] = o;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh and do you have a hint on how I could do that?

Comment: Thank you, now I know what you mean!
Do you know why that's the case? Since I'm coming from c and there it was possible.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'm mistaking.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is being invoked, but is not initialising the `CharField` member.  Instead it is creating a local array named `CharField` (which, although having the same name, is distinct from the struct member named `CharField`), initialising it, and that array no longer exists when the constructor completes.

The constructor implementation

```
field()
    {
        char PlayField[5][5] = { { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o } };
    }
```

has exactly the same effect (no change of the struct member named `CharField`) as

```
field()
    {
        char unused_data[5][5] = { { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o } };
    }
```

The only thing that has changed is the name of the temporary array created in the body of the constructor.

To actually initialise the `PlayField` member, change this contructor to use an initialiser list

```
 field() : PlayField { { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o }, { o, o, o, o, o } }
    {  // body of constructor is here
    };
```

or (before C++11) where this form isn't supported.

```
field()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
           for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
                CharField[5][5] = o;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time commitment

Comment: To whoever marked down this answer, doing so without explanation is poor form.