# How to generalize plain 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

For C++, I have seen several recommendations to use a 2D arrays as follows:

```
int* theArray = new int[d1 * d2];
```

An element (i, j) can then be accessed as follows:

```
int myInt = theArray[i + d2 * j];
```

I have two questions: First, how to access a 3D array? Is there a general formula? Second and more important, will there be a performance penalty if I use functions

```
int getNumber(int i, int j, int k) 
void setNumber(int i, int j, int k, int theValue)
```

to retrieve and set number? I don't want to screw it up somewhere in the code and then spend forever finding where that screw up is.

Comment: The indexing is `i + d2*j + d2*d3*k`, but this is a basic mathematic question, not programming.

Comment: btw, this depends on the dimension order.

Comment: As this is tagged `array` I just had to answer: use `std::array`, of if run-time size setting is required, std::vector. Optimize further only after profiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalization to three dimension is not difficult:

```
int* theArray = new int[d1*d2*d3];
```

and accessing it using

```
int myInt = theArray[i+d1*(j+d2*k)];
```

Just like decimal system for example. When you write 123 as 3+10*2+100*3 = 3 + 10*(2+10*3). Where 10 is the size of each dimension. Note that I have changed your d2 to d1, as what is indented is the size of the dimension associated to the index i.

Regarding your second question, the function called can reduce the performances. But you can avoid this issue by [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) the function, or defining a [macro](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), which is then equivalent to no function call at all, regarding performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say for 2D array, assuming `i` is the first index and `j` is the second, it's better to do indexing  like

```
int myInt = theArray[i*d2 + j];
```

so changing the last index gives you contiguous range. This is how C and C++ multi-dimensional arrays are implemented.

So if your 3D array is

```
int* theArray = new int[d1*d2*d3];
```

Then you access it this way:

```
int myInt = theArray[(i*d2 + j)*d3 + k];
```

Regarding accessor functions - if they are inline, the overhead will be zero. You may want also to wrap this all into your custom array class (but that's probably what you are already intending to do)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `std::array` instead and not do any manual index calculations. Just make sure that the last index is the one you will most likely loop over. std::array is as fast as [].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {

    constexpr size_t a=5;
    constexpr size_t b=4;
    constexpr size_t c=3;

    std::array<std::array<std::array<float,a>, b>, c> arr3d;

    for(auto& outer : arr3d){
      for(auto& row : outer){
        for(auto& place : row){
          place=3.5;
        }
      }
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<a; ++i){
      for(size_t j=0;j<b; ++j){
        for(size_t k=0;k<c; ++k){
          arr3d[i][j][k]=k; // or whatever
        }
      }
    }

    std::cout << arr3d[0][1][2] << std::endl;
}
```

If you need run-time flexibility for the sizes, use `std::vector`.

```
template<typename T> using Vec = std::vector<T>;    
Vec<Vec<Vec<float>>> arr3d(a,Vec<Vec<float>>(b,Vec<float>(c,0)));
```

but it is going to be significantly slower to initialize and depending on how you use it (and the values of a,b,c) access will be slower also. (**note comments**).

For other ways to initialize the array: [Other ways to initialize the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869357/constructor-gets-ignored/29869564#29869564)

Comment: you're assuming the size is known at compile time.

Comment: A vector of vectors of vectors will be a heap allocated array of pointers to heap allocated arrays of pointers to heap allocated arrays of objects. If a flat array is used as in Tony's answer, there is only one heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

To see how this is solved in a more general way, you can have a look at [boost multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).